# How to forward a node request using axios?

Tags: node.js, express, proxy, axios, request

In my express.js server I am doing this to forward a request to another server

```
async handleRequest(req, res) {
    const serverUrl = "http://localhost:4000"

    await req.pipe(request({ url: serverUrl + req.url })).pipe(res);
}
```

This is working as expected.
But I have decided to use `axios` or `got` library instead of request since request is no longer maintained.
But something like this is not working -

```
req.pipe(axios({url: serverUrl + req.url})).pipe(res);
```

I am getting error

```
(node:88124) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: dest.on is not a function
    at IncomingMessage.Readable.pipe (internal/streams/readable.js:671:8)
```

How can I fix this? I want to forward the request as it is without making any changes in the request object.

Comment: how do you import `request`?

Comment: @Waelsy123 `import request from "request";`

Comment: just added an answer, I hope that will help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `responseType` parameter with value `stream` so axios give you the option to pipe your response data as a stream by:

```
axiosResponse.data.pipe(destination); // where destination can be a file or another stream
```

Also, in fact there is no need to do `await req.pipe` because axios will stream the response into your express response (res) object

hence is the full answer:

```
  const axiosResponse = await axios({
    url: serverUrl + req.url,
    responseType: 'stream'
  })

  axiosResponse.data.pipe(res)
```