# What is the Axios equivalent of req.pipe(request()) / Pipe express request data into Axios request

Tags: node.js, express, axios

Using [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) you can forward a `POST multipart/form-data` request from [express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express) to another server without modifying the body/parameters of the initial request and then return the response from the other server to express. With [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) this feature appears to be missing.

CODE:
header

```js
const request = require('request');
const axios = require('axios');

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.listen(3000);

const FORWARD_URL = 'https://example.com/'
```

Working example using request

```js
app.post('/test/0', (req, res) => {
    req.pipe(request(FORWARD_URL)).pipe(res);
})
```

Attempt #1

```js
app.post('/test/1', (req, res) => {
    req.pipe(axios.post(FORWARD_URL)).pipe(res);
})

// internal/streams/readable.js:827
//       dests[i].emit('unpipe', this, { hasUnpiped: false });
//                ^
// TypeError: dests[i].emit is not a function
//     at IncomingMessage.Readable.unpipe (internal/streams/readable.js:827:16)
//     at unpipe (S:\_Work\[REDACTED]\node_modules\unpipe\index.js:47:12)
//     at send (S:\_Work\[REDACTED]\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:306:3)
//     at Immediate.<anonymous> (S:\_Work\[REDACTED]\node_modules\finalhandler\index.js:133:5)
//     at Immediate.<anonymous> (S:\_Work\[REDACTED]\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:635:15)
//     at processImmediate (internal/timers.js:466:21)
```

Attempt #2

```js
app.post('/test/2', (req, res) => {
    req.pipe(axios({
        url: FORWARD_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'stream'
    })).pipe(res);
})

// SAME ERROR AS ABOVE
```

Attempt #3

```js
app.post('/test/3', async (req, res) => {
    const axiosRequest = await axios({
        url: FORWARD_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'stream',
        data: req
    })

    axiosRequest.data.pipe(res);
})
// server at FORWARD_URL receives improperly formatted request body, changing request content-type headers has no affect
// ------WebKitFormBoundaryc4BjPwpdR4mG7CFN
// Content-Disposition: form-data; name="field_name"
//
// field_value
// ------WebKitFormBoundaryc4BjPwpdR4mG7CFN--
```

A similar issue has been addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66916839/7594368), the accepted answer, while not very clear, does answer the question, however, only covers `GET` & `POST application/x-www-form-urlencoded` requests, This is regarding `POST multipart/form-data` requests.

Ideally I'm looking for a solution that functions identically to the [request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) example using [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), this works great for my use case as it includes file uploads, because of this, I want to avoid parsing the body and instead just forwarding it onto the next server.

Testing of the above routes was performed with [postman](https://www.postman.com/)

Comment: were you ever able to get this working?

Comment: @DannyHarding, Affraid not - we ended up having to leave request in there :(

Answer (score 0):

Changing the Axios request headers to the equivalent ones obtained from the original request, resolved the error for me.

Code:

```js
    const axiosRequest = await axios({
        url: FORWARD_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'stream',
        data: req
    })
```

I have just copied the original request headers to the new request

```js
    const axiosRequest = await axios({
        url: FORWARD_URL,
        method: 'POST',
        responseType: 'stream',
        data: req,
        headers: {
            ...req.headers
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me for POSTing streams with content type `multipart/form-data`:

```js
app.post('/test/0', async (req, res) => {
  const response = await axios.post(FORWARD_URL, req, {
    headers: {
      'content-type': req.headers['content-type'],
    },
  });

  return res.send(response.data);
})
```

In my case I did not need to set the `responseType` header to `stream`. This might depend on the response you are getting from the API.

What is important is:

- posting the entire request object (not just the `body`!)
- setting the `content-type` header of the outgoing request to the same value as the incoming request

Passing just the body of the incoming request to the outgoing request will result in the API (the reader of the stream) endpoint receiving an empty object (which it will initialise with default values).

Passing the body of the incoming request and setting the content-type header will result in the API endpoint receiving a null body.